# How to auto-login (remember-me) with custom authentication in Spring?

Tags: spring, security, authentication, remember-me

i'm writing an WebApp with Spring. I created an custom login (why is unimportant) that works. Then Now I want to add the remember-me functionality to it. I managed to set the cookie but now I don't know how to auto-login the user. So how do I login the user when he revisits the site?

Here is my authentication Method:

```
public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    try {
        AuthenticatedUser user = authService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (new BCryptPasswordEncoder().matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());

            rememberMeService.loginSuccess(request, response, auth);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here my WebConfiguration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/VAADIN/**", "/HEARTBEAT/**", "/UIDL/**", "/resources/**", "/manifest.json", "/icons/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/frontend/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/h2-console/**",
                "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**",
                "/signup", "/signup**", "/signup/**", "/")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
    .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeService())
    .and()
    .logout().permitAll();
}

@Bean
public TokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeService() {
    TokenBasedRememberMeServices tbrms = 
            new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("rememberMe", userDetailsService);
    tbrms.setAlwaysRemember(true);
    return tbrms;
}
```

Comment: Nobody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have in my app:

In your WebCofiguration

```
rememberMe().key("superUniqueAndSecretKey")
```

And you also have to add a remember-me checkbox in the login form (I guess you are missing this)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" />
```

(The name `remember-me` is the default for spring 5)

Check this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-remember-me

Comment: I'm not using a form. That's why I'm using an custom authentication.